# Calculate the rotation angle of a vector python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, rotation

I am trying to find the rotation `angle` of a 2D `vector`. I have found a few questions that use 3D `vectors`. The following `df` represents a single `vector` with the first `row` as the origin.

```
d = ({      
    'X' : [10,12.5,17,20,16,14,13,8,7],                 
    'Y' : [10,12,13,8,6,7,8,8,9],                             
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I can rotate a vector using the following equation:

```
angle = x
theta = (x/180) * numpy.pi

rotMatrix = numpy.array([[numpy.cos(theta), -numpy.sin(theta)], 
                         [numpy.sin(theta),  numpy.cos(theta)]])
```

But I'm not sure how I would find the `angle` at each point of time using the coordinates listed above. Apologies for using a `df`. It replicates my actual `dataset`

Comment: What do the coordinates in your dataset represent? Does each (x,y) pair represent a vector from the origin to the point (x,y)? Between which two "lines" are you measuring this angle?

Comment: @Carol Ng, the question has been updated sorry. It is a single vector. I want to measure the rotation angle at each point of time. So between points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should move the origin to `(0, 0)`, then you can use `np.arctan2()` which calculates the angle and defines the quadrant correctly. The result is already in radians (theta) so you don't need it in degrees (alpha).

```
d = {'X' : [10,12.5,17,20,16,14,13,8,7],                
     'Y' : [10.,12,13,8,6,7,8,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# move the origin
x = df["X"] - df["X"][0]
y = df["Y"] - df["Y"][0]

df["theta"] = np.arctan2(y, x)
df["aplha"] = np.degrees(df["theta"])
df
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas. This just calculate the rotation angle referenced from the origin doesn't it.

Comment: Yes, and by origin I mean first row of df, `(10, 10)`